# Move Magento2 cart page items header to bottom section

Tags: magento2

I would like to move the section with cart update, continue shopping buttons to bottom of the product items table. Please see this screenshot https://prnt.sc/22k9QQRwt4rn

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the cart item actions are placed at the bottom of the item list. That is a customization of your theme. You has to contact theme's support or have a developer to review the theme's code.